# How can I automatically copy data from one Excel sheet to another and have it sort into specific cells?

Tags: excel-formula

## How to copy data from one excel spreadsheet to another where the copied data  gets automatically sorted into specific cells

Im looking to copy data from one spread sheet into another which has the same cell column. How can i copy this data so that it automatically gets placed  into the correct cell number without doing it manually?

[image]

Tried all sorts of sorting methods but cant get it to work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think this is a good question, but could you please: (1) [make a table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/2057969) or embed the image (as opposed to just giving a link) and (2) clarify the question (also in the title) to say that the merging should happen in a way that cell values are matched up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at XLOOKUP:

```
=XLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:B,"",0,1)
```

[image]